# Is there a programatic way to get all the information showm on the EC2 Service Limits page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Could someone tell me if exists a programmatically way, or from command line, for example using awscli, to get all the information, that is showed on the "EC2 Service Limits" page?

I've used this command: ec2 describe-account-attributes
, but it gives only a general information, but I need to know as well such information as:

Running On-Demand c1.medium instances,
Running On-Demand c1.xlarge instances
etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find is:

```
aws support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result \
    --check-id eW7HH0l7J9 \
    --query 'result.sort_by(flaggedResources[?status!="ok"],&metadata[2])[?starts_with(metadata[2],`On-Demand`)].metadata' \
    --output table \
    --region us-east-1
```

This seems to return only non-default limits though. My output looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                       DescribeTrustedAdvisorCheckResult                       |
+-----------+------+------------------------------------+-------+-----+---------+
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - c3.2xlarge  |  xxx  |  1  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - c4.2xlarge  |  xxx  |  0  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - c4.2xlarge  |  xxxx |  0  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - c4.xlarge   |  xxx  |  0  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - c4.xlarge   |  xxxx |  9  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - m3.xlarge   |  xxx  |  1  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - m4.large    |  xxx  |  7  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - m4.large    |  xxx  |  8  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - m4.xlarge   |  xxx  |  34 |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - m4.xlarge   |  xxx  |  97 |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - r4.2xlarge  |  xx   |  8  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - r4.2xlarge  |  xx   |  8  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.medium   |  xxx  |  1  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.medium   |  xxxx |  1  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.micro    |  xxx  |  2  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.micro    |  xxxx |  2  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.nano     |  xxxx |  1  |  Green  |
|  us-east-1|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.small    |  xxx  |  5  |  Green  |
|  us-west-2|  EC2 |  On-Demand instances - t2.small    |  xxxx |  8  |  Green  |
+-----------+------+------------------------------------+-------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: When running above command I get:
An error occurred (SubscriptionRequiredException) when calling the DescribeTrustedAdvisorCheckResult operation: AWS Premium Support Subscription is required to use this service.

Comment: :( Apparently, you need premium support to be able to run that command.

Comment: Use of AWS Premium Support Subscription requires some payments, but without it exists a free solution ?